# using jquery and ajax to insert multiple checkbox using foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hi I have this input field,

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbCmat$count_FRID" value= "".$count_FRID."" 
name="rubric_chkbox[]"  />
```

and I'm using jquery and ajax to get the value from that checkbox,

```
var rubricChkbox = $("input[name='rubric_chkbox[]']").val();

$.ajax({
        url: "Queries/save.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
        "rubricChkbox":rubricChkbox
        },
        success: function(yey){
          console.log(yey);
          alert(yey);
        }
      });
```

And my Queries/save.php is this,

```
if (isset($_POST['rubricChkbox'])) {
    foreach($_POST['rubricChkbox'] as $rubric) {

        $rubric_value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $rubric);

        $sql_raw = "INSERT INTO rubric_selected (raw_selected_rubric, Saved)

        VALUES  ('$rubric_value', '1')";

        $success = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_raw); 

        $sql_to_validated = "INSERT INTO validated_score (selected_rubric)

        VALUES  ('$rubric_value')";

        $success = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_to_validated); 
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error,
 Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Any idea what's wrong please? Thank you.

Comment: `value="<?php echo $count_FRID;?>"` assuming you are loading that in PHP but not in a `<?php ...?>` block

Comment: Maybe you should show us MORE of how you create that field in your PHP script

Comment: How many fields do you have called `name="rubric_chkbox[]"` I assume more than one as it is named as an array

Comment: That value="".$count_FRID."" is already in a php echo statement sir.

Comment: Then SHOW THE WHOLE statement, as it looks wrong to me